# Cannot consume ASP.NET Core web API after publishing to IIS

Tags: asp.net-core, iis, visual-studio-2017, asp.net-core-2.2, .net-core-2.2

I have a winform application that is meant to call an api to login and do other things.
When I run the api (.net core 2.2) on visual studio, and try to consume it from the WinsForm, it works fine. I later published the api and hosted it on IIS. It works fine when I launch it but the WinsForm won't work with the link I got from it (localhost/powerapi/login). It doesn't give an error, just doesn't work. I tried Fiddler with it(using the link from the IIS), it worked perfectly. Why is it not working with the WinsForm??
Please help.

**UPDATE**
I debugged again and found this error. It actually tries to call the API but it gets an error 500: Internal Server Error. I tried it on fiddler and got same error too. [This is the screenshot of the error from visual studio](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cgMU9.png)

What i mean by "it works well" is that the api works well when i launch it from IIS into the browser(so as to get its link which is passed into "url" in the screenshot). And by IIS i mean local machine.
Also, the winform and the api on the same server because I'm currently running them on my pc.

Comment: Can you share some code from how you are trying to have it work?

Comment: "It works fine when I launch it", what does that mean? "hosted it on IIS", local IIS or a remote machine? What's the site bindings? You missed too much detail above.

Comment: As far as I know, if your winform and your web api application is not at the same server. You couldn't access the api application by using localhost domain. If your winform application and  the web application in the same domain, you could use the server's ip address to access it. If they are not in the same domain, you should by a public Ip address, then you could use that public ipaddress to access the server.

Comment: please check the question, I have included an image and explained better too.